# Query Error: "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating ..."

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010, crystal-reports-2010

This is the table, and this is my query.

[image]

```
MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT FS_Expenses.ID, FS_Expenses.FS_Date, FS_Expenses.SupplierID, " & _
  "FS_Expenses.Total, FS_Expenses.PaymentType, FS_Expenses.PaymentDate, " & _
  "FS_Expenses.TotalPayment, FS_Expenses.PaymentDue, " & _
  "Supplier.SupplierName, " & _
  "Supplier.Address, Supplier.ContactNo, " & _
  "Supplier.EmailID FROM " & _
  "(FS_Expenses INNER JOIN Supplier ON FS_Expenses.SupplierID = Supplier.SupplierID) " & _
  "where FS_Date between #" & DateFrom.Value.Date & "# And #" & DateTo.Value.Date & "# order by FS_Date"
```

I believe it's because **two of the Supplier ID (Primary Key from another table) should not co-exist** in the same field, thus, "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints." **No errors if there's only 1 Supplier ID.**

But I need to show more than these ID's in the report I am generating.

What do I do?

Thanks for any ideas!

(SupplierID is Text type)

Comment: How would a `select` query trigger a constraint violation?

Comment: Sorry @Gordon I am not sure about that since I just apply what I learned from Googling. Can I help you check for perhaps my properties or settings somewhere?

Comment: . .  My best guess is that you are trying to change the value in the grid to a value that already exists.

Comment: Actually I only use the query to display the data in the report. If I remove the other row, it works just fine, but only displays the data in the first row.

Comment: Why do you want to return `SupplierID` column twice? In `Expr1` there is duplicate value same as in `FS_Expenses.SupplierID`.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331463/failed-to-enable-constraints-one-or-more-rows-contain-values-violating-non-null

Comment: @VDohnal okay I removed either one of them but the error still persists. :( ... updated post.

Comment: @VDohnal thanks for the reference. It says there something about "verifying the database within the Crystal Reports designer." But how exactly does this mean? Sorry if this seems obvious. I'd start Googling for it though.

Comment: Your query is now ok, the problem is within your report, but I do not have Crystal Reports installed now... I bet when you run this query in Access then there is no problem.

Comment: Much appreciated @VDohnal! I guess it simply meant right-clicking in the "Database Field" in the right menu, and "Verify Database."